# Program couldnt find the path Partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a dropdownlist that when someone select some item in dropdown it need to be render partial and that partial loading some checkboxes.I trying to render partial but it keeps throwing not found error.I'm sure about path

Is it related with Html.Partial or Html.RenderPartial ?

My Controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult SendCheckList(string input)
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
      return null;

     FormDetailViewModel model = new FormDetailViewModel();
     int id =Convert.ToInt32(input);
     ItemsRepository items = new ItemsRepository();
     CheckListRepository checkListRep = new CheckListRepository();
     CheckList checkList = db.CheckLists.FirstOrDefault(t => 
     t.CheckListTypeId == id);
     List<Item> İtems = db.Items.Where(t => t.ItemId == 
     checkList.ItemId).ToList();
     foreach (Item item in İtems)
     {
       İtemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
       item.ItemId.ToString(), Text = item.ItemDesc });
     }
       model.İtems = İtemList;
       return PartialView 
      ("~/Areas/User/Views/FormDetail/SendCheckList.cshtml", model);
      }
```

My View:

```
 <script 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/open.js"></script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
  <td>
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormDetail.CheckListType)
  </td>
   <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FormDetail.CheckListTypeId, 
     Model.checkLists, new { @id = "Selection", @class = "drop-open"})
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Js/Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#Selection').on('change', function () {           
 $('#results').load('@Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/User/Views/FormDetail/ 
 SendCheckList.cshtml")')
  });
  });
```

Comment: add attribute [ChildActionOnly]

Comment: You can't render a partial view using only jQuery. You can, however, call a method (action) that will render the partial view for you and add it to the page using jQuery/AJAX. In your `load` function, do something like this: `$('#results').load('@Url.Action("SendCheckList")')`

Comment: Did this work in your case? @Eralp

Comment: I used url and render the partial in that url.

Comment: Something like this: `$('#results').load('@Url.Action("SendCheckList","FormDetail")')` ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. You need to make some changes in the JQuery.

```
public ActionResult SendCheckList(string input)
{
  ---
  ---
  ---
  return PartialView("~~/Areas/User/Views/FormDetail/SendCheckList.cshtml", mode);
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#Selection').on('change', function () {     
    var obj = {};
    obj.parameter = parameter;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/SendCheckList',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        async: false
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $("#DivID").html(data);
    });          
  });
);
```